# Class Library (Portable) UWP + WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015, uwp

Criei um projeto simples `Portable Class Library` que está sendo utilizada em dois projetos `WPF e UWP`.

Os dois projetos funcionam normalmente, porém, o projeto `UWP` ao compilar apresenta as seguintes mensagem de erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Embora o projeto funcione normalmente me intrigou esta mensagem, alguém saberia o motivo?

`project.json`

```
{
  "supports": {
    "net46.app": {},
    "uwp.10.0.app": {}
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility": "1.0.1",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    ".NETStandard1.3": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema era `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` desatualizado no projeto `WUP`, foi só procurar atualização via `Nuget` e o problema foi resolvido.

Nada como usa visita ao `Nuget` de vez em quando para solucionar alguns problemas.

Vejam o antes e depois:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]